# Export remote Database : Oracle

Tags: database, oracle, export

I have an oracle database on a server that contains more than one database, i'm connected to those databases using sqlDevelopper normaly. I want to export the database DB1.
The string connection used in SqlDevelopper is :

> user@//server:1530/DB1 
>   user@//server:1533/DB2 
>   user@//server:1534/DB3

The command i use to export the DB1 is :

> exp user@//server:1530/DB1 file="C:\DB1.dmp" log="C:\DB1.log" rows=y
>   owner=user

But it doesn't work, i have this message :

> ```
> EXP-00056: Erreur ORACLE 6401 rencontré
> ORA-06401: NETCMN : désignation de lecteur non valide
> EXP-00000: Procédure d'export terminée avec erreur
> ```

How can I adjust the exp command to have the desired result?

Comment: What database and `exp` versions are you using? The 10g and 11g versions of `exp` seem to recognise that 'easy connect' syntax, but the 9i version doesn't. (If you are on a later version than 9i, you should probably be using `expdp` in preference to `exp` anyway). If you are using 9i `exp` and can't use a later version then you probably need to use a TNS alias, defined in your `tnsnames.ora`.

Comment: I've created an alis on my tnsnames
`BD1=
(DESCRIPTION = 
    (ADDRESS_LIST = 
      (ADDRESS = 
        (PROTOCOL = TCP)
        (HOST = server)
        (PORT = 1530)
      )
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA = 
      (SERVICE_NAME = DB1)
    )
  )`
How can i use it now?

Comment: Be aware that exporting data remotely will be much slower than exporting locally and transferring over network.

Answer (score 7):

Following on from comments suggesting you're using a pre-10g version that doesn't support the [easy connect](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E14072_01/network.112/e10836/naming.htm#i498306) syntax, and therefore also can't use [data pump](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e22490/dp_export.htm)...

If you've created a `tnsnames.ora` entry like:

```
BD1 =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP) (HOST = server) (PORT = 1530))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA = (SERVICE_NAME = DB1))
  )
```

... then you should be able to export using:

```
exp user@BD1 file="C:\DB1.dmp" log="C:\DB1.log" rows=y owner=user
```

(where `BD1` is the alias name; not sure if you intended to spell it like that, but you could use `DB1` if you preferred).

Comment: That is exactely what i did but still have another error : 
EXP-00056: ORACLE error 12541 encountered
ORA-12541: TNS:no listener
EXP-00000: Export terminated unsuccessfully

Comment: @Potinos - that suggests the `server` or `1530` are wrong, since there doesn't seem to be a listener at `server:1530`. Possibly a typo, or the data you have for the SQL Developer connection is out of date, or maybe something odd is happening with name resolution. Or you already had an entry in a `tnsnames.ora` and you aren't using the one you think. Try `tnsping BD1` and check what that says it's connecting to.

Comment: I supposed that too, but i'm connected to server at 1530 with sqlDevelopper and no matter!